# Homomorphic Image of ideal in Lie algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, group-homomorphism, maximal-and-prime-ideals, vector-space-isomorphism

I try to prove the following theorem which given without proof here [On Prime Ideals of Lie Algebras](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.hmj/1206136843)

> **Theorem:** Let $L$ and $L^{\prime}$ be Lie algebras and let $f: L \rightarrow L^{\prime}$ be a surjective homomorphism. Then an ideal $P$ of $L$ containing $\mathrm{Ker} f$ is prime if and only if $f(P)$ is prime in $L^{\prime}$.

> *My Proof:* Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $L$, let $H$ and $K$ are two ideals of $L^{\prime}$. Suppose that $[H,K] \subseteq f(P)$, then $f^{-1}([H,K]) \subseteq f^{-1}f(P)$, hence $\Big [f^{-1}(H),f^{-1}(K)\Big] \subseteq P$.
> But $P$ is prime, then $f^{-1}(H) \subseteq P$ or $f^{-1}(K) \subseteq P$. Since $f$ is surjective homomorphism, thus
> $H \subseteq f(P) \textit{ or } K \subseteq f(P)$. Therefore $f(P)$ is prime.

Is this proof true?

Is this step $f^{-1}([H,K])= \Big [f^{-1}(H),f^{-1}(K)\Big]$ true?

Is this step $f^{-1}f(P)=P$ true?

Is this theorem is a trivial conclusion of Isomorphism Theorems of Lie algebra and we do not need this proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correctly identified the weak points of your argument:

(1) Is this step $f^{-1}([H,K])= \Big [f^{-1}(H),f^{-1}(K)\Big]$ true?

No, in general this is not true.  If the Lie bracket on $L$ was zero, then the right hand side would be $0$, but the left hand side would contain ker$(f)$.

However for your purpose all you need is:
$$f^{-1}([H,K])\supseteq \Big [f^{-1}(H),f^{-1}(K)\Big],$$ which is true.  To see this just apply $f$ to an element of the right hand side, and clearly you will land in $[H,K]$.

(2) Is this step $f^{-1}f(P)=P$ true?

Yes, but only because of one specific bit of information you were given, which you should mention to justify the statement.  Namely ker$(f)\subseteq P$.  Thus if $x\in f^{-1}f(P)$ then $f(x)=f(p)$ for some $p \in P$, and $$x=(x-p)+p,$$ with $p\in P$ and $x-p\in$ker$(f)\subseteq P$.

Comment: Is this theorem is a trivial conclusion of Isomorphism Theorems of Lie algebra and we do not need this proof?

Comment: @HamadaAl Not as far as I can see.